# PHP XML: Getting text of a node and its children

Tags: php, xml, xpath, simplexml

I know that this questions has been asked before, but I cannot make it work. I'm using simplexml and xpath in a PHP file. I need to get text from a node including the text in its child nodes. So, the results should be:

```
Mr.Smith bought a white convertible car.
```

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test9.xsl"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <description>
            <name>Mr.Smith bought a <car>white</car> <car>convertible</car> car.</name>
        </description>
    </item>
</items>
```

The php that's not working is:

```
$text = $xml->xpath('//items/item/description/name');
    foreach($text as &$value) {
        echo $value;
}
```

Please help!

Comment: post the current output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the node value with all its child elements, you can use [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php), with [`C14n()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php):

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test9.xsl"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <description>
            <name>Mr.Smith bought a <car>white</car> <car>convertible</car> car.</name>
        </description>
    </item>
</items>
XML;
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$x = new DOMXpath($doc);
$text = $x->query('//items/item/description/name');
echo $text[0]->C14n(); // Mr.Smith bought a white convertible car.
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/tivXL)

Comment: Or simply `$text[0]->nodeValue;` even `$text[0]->textContent;`

Comment: @Parfait thanks! Figured he needed the tags in there too, for some reason.

Comment: I'm not getting anything for some reason. Have you tested it?

Comment: @SteveDEU I did, see the demo. Try Patfait’s code too.

Comment: When I work on html parsing not xml parsing. I get an error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::C14N() ` why is this and how do I solve this.

Comment: @indianwebdevil `c14n()` is a method for `DOMNode`, not `DOMNodeList`